# Can Strongloop process manager control worker processes?

Tags: strongloop

Anyone know how I might use strong-pm to control a worker process, instead of a web app? I run the web app in the typical manner, via sl-pm, but I also want to run a worker process that is also part of the application. I want to deploy the web app to one docker container, and the worker process to another.

Essentially, how do I use strong-pm in a similar fashion as pm2, where you can specify the commands that you want pm2 to control?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Maybe will help someone else later.

`slc run` is what ultimately starts the node process on the server. according to `slc run` docs, it first looks in package.json for scripts.start and falls back to main section. So that was a dead end. I instead used an env var carefully placed in server.js to differentiate between the web app and my worker process. Something like process.env.START_WORKERS

```
# in server.js, within default loopback boot function
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module) {
    if (+process.env.START_WORKERS) {
      require('./workers/start');
      return;
    } else {
      app.start();
    }
  }
});
```